# Entity framework 6 and oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Note:
Entity Framework 6 is not supported at this time. Some Visual Studio versions may default to Entity Framework 6. If so, set your .NET project to use an earlier version of Entity Framework.

The message is provided in the [Oracle Data Provider's system requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149)

Is this the status still the same for today, or am I seeing an old message.

I am aware of dotConnect for Oracle from Devart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 is still not supported by ODAC 12c (or any other version). Supported EFs are 4.5 and 5. Third party products, e.g. Devart, seems to be the only option at the moment. 
I haven't seen any announcement from Oracle to indicate possible release date.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Product Manager Alex Keh had this to say in [this discussion thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3527318) on March 6, 2014:

> You can run EF5 apps in EF 6 right now with ODAC 12c R2. The next ODAC
>   release will include true EF 6 support. The plan is to release it
>   sometime this year.

A casual search didn't turn up any predictions more current or specific than this.  So we can expect Oracle to support Entity Framework 6 sometime in 2014.

**Update**: [ODP.NET 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) now advertises support for Entity Framework 6.

Comment: What exactly does this mean:
"You can run EF5 apps in EF 6 right now with ODAC 12c R2."? I'm using EF 6 in a project and need to hook it against an Oracle db. How do I do this?

Comment: I believe this means that if you are able to compile your code against Entity Framework 5 (i.e., you're not leveraging any features only available in Entity Framework 6), then the same code would function under Entity Framework 6.  You might try checking out this [YouTube video from Christian Shay at Oracle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68tlel4iJdM) to get a feel for how to use the Oracle developer tools with Entity Framework.