# trouble with generating oracle data-model in .net MVC entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-6, datamodel, odac

We have installed ODAC 12c Release 3 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.1) in our project. We managed to generate Oracle Data Model in EF5, but could not do this in EF6 in our MVC project. How can we generate in EF6?

I read about this in :
[Entity framework 6 and oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317643/entity-framework-6-and-oracle)

but is it true that it still doesn't support ef6?